# Comparing Digits For At Least 4 Differences

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In A1 I have 19732003, in B1 I have 19811975. I want to compare A1 and B1 to see if at least 4 of the digits have changed. This needs to be all in one function, not 8 separate functions. I have tried RIGHT/LEFT MID/CENTER to no avail. I am not adept at working with macros or VBA, so I need a formula please. Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance for any help.

```
Cell Value
 A1  19732003
 B1  19811975
     --------
```

Results
T/F  00111111 now count the # of 1"s, are there at least 4, if so in C1 Put True

In English this is what I am asking Excel to do.

- Is digit 1 of A1's value different than digit 1 of B1's value,True False, check the next digit
- Is digit 2 of A1's value different than digit 2 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 3 of A1's value different than digit 3 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 4 of A1's value different than digit 4 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 5 of A1's value different than digit 5 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 6 of A1's value different than digit 6 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 7 of A1's value different than digit 7 of B1's value  True False
- Is digit 8 of A1's value different than digit 8 of B1's value  True False

Answer (score 3):

This will iterate an 8 digit number and test each digit with the corresponding digit in the other number.  If not equal it returns 1 to the count.

After iterating it test if the output is greater than or equal to 4 and reports TRUE if it is, and FALSE if not:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,ROW($1:$8),1)<>MID(B1,ROW($1:$8),1)))>=4
```

[image]